# What's the meaning of percentile values in diskspd output?

Tags: hard-drive, performance

[image]

Does this mean that:

25th percentile means 25% requests had latency of 3.475ms

90th percentile means 90% requests had latency of 24.306ms

4 nines means 99.99% requests had latency of 55.296ms

Is this what it means?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.** From the table you posted, I'd conclude,

- 25% of read requests completed within 3.475ms (meaning, 3.475ms or less).
- 50% of read requests completed within 3.983ms.
- 75% of read requests completed within 19.848ms.
- 4-nines (99.99%) of read requests completed within 55.296ms.
- etc.

So it gives you a feel for performance distribution. Not just that the median is 3.983ms, but how typical it is to get a much-slower-than-median response time. In this case, you know that the slowest 25% of your reads (those *not* falling in the fastest 75%) take at least 5x longer than the median, and the very slowest request took more than 20x.

Comment: I don't quite get this. Why didn't they just say 25%, why use the word percentile?

Comment: They have similar meanings, but percentile is a specific type of percent. Percent only means a certain quantity of the whole, but it could contain any jumbled values from the whole. If you want to first sort the whole by some metric, then talk about percents in tiers from lowest to highest—that's percentile. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile